# Visual Studio Team Services Build Issues

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com) as source control and have enabled continuous integration.

My project is an ASP.NET application which used Entity Framework 5. When i checkin the code and the build controller tries to build it, the following errors come up

> DataModel\GenomicsTutorDataModel.Context.cs (40): The type or
>   namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1578): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

In my solution i have made system.data.entity CopyLocal = True yet no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is Entity Framework coming from NuGet? If so, you should be able to enable NuGet package restore, which should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are on a **64 bits** machine and the TFS server is not?
Try to build your project for **Any CPU** or **x86**.

Answer (score 0):

Add the DLL you referenced for `System.Data.Entity` into a folder in your `project` or somewhere in a folder in the `Source Control` and reference to that one. Check this in and try to build your application again.